# C# - Multi-Threading Pause

Tags: c#, multithreading, system

Here's a code I made in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace xyz
{
    class Program
    {
        Thread t1, t2;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program go = new Program();
            go.actual();
        }
        public void actual()
        {
            t1 = new Thread(timer);
            t2 = new Thread(inputting);
            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
        }
        public void timer()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            t2.Abort();
            Console.WriteLine("5 seconds passed!");
        }
        public void inputting()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please wait 5 seconds...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is, when the console says "5 seconds passed!" (after aborting the `t2` thread), it doesn't exit right away. This text stays there for a couple of seconds and then the console exits.

The thing is, if I press a key (of the `ReadKey` method) before the thread aborts, it displays the "5 seconds passed!" text and then it exits right away.

If I don't click any key, and the `ReadKey` method doesn't happen, it just displays the text for a couple of seconds.

Why is that? Is it a bug? And can I fix it?

Comment: Because it's cleaning up the threads? I can't think of any other reason.

Comment: Yeah, but if I aborted the thread which has the "Console.ReadKey()", the ReadKey command should be also aborted, since it is a part of the thread I aborted.

Comment: 1. Don't abort threads, your just asking for trouble and 2. why are you creating a new instance of `Program`? Just call `actual`.

Comment: It still has to cleanup the first thread upon exiting. I'm not sure you've actually been 100% clear on what you're experiencing. You said the text stays there. I wouldn't expect it to leave. But you're acting like it just takes a while for the application to close. You have to be a lot clearer.

Comment: It should just close immediately. Cannot see anything wrong myself.
However, you may want to look into creating the Threads as a `BackgroundThread` so when the main Thread of the application closes these are automatically closed, to stop processing after your application has complete.

Comment: OK, I'll be more clear here. After the "5 seconds passed!" text appears, I expect it to exit immediately, because there is nothing after the "Console.WriteLine". However, after the "5 seconds passed!" text is displayed, I have to press a key to exit, even though I aborted Thread t2, which has the ReadKey in it.

Comment: Here's a photo: http://i.imgur.com/gszjVSi.png

Comment: See? It just stays there until I press a key, even though I've aborted the thread which contains the ReadKey().

Answer (score 0):

The result you are seeing seems reasonable to me, calling `Thread.Abort` isn't going to somehow unblock the Console so it will still be waiting for input. Regardless, you should avoid calling `Thread.Abort` as there is no guarantee that it will work as expected. It's a much better approach to build cancellation support into your threads and there are various ways to do this.

Alternatively, just use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) which has it all build in already.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I see that you basically want to timeout the `Console.ReadKey` call after a certain amount of time. Unfortunately, `ReadKey` does not have a timeout parameter. That is okay. We can wrap it in a method that does. You do not need to use any asynchronous mechanisms to accomplish this. Just use `Console.KeyAvailable` in a synchronous polling loop.

```
public static class ConsoleEx
{
  public static bool TryReadKey(TimeSpan timeout, out ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo)
  {
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    return TryReadKey(timeout, cts.Token, out keyinfo);
  }

  public static bool TryReadKey(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellation, out ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo)
  {
    keyinfo = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
    DateTime latest = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(timeout);
    do
    {
        cancellation.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        if (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
            return true;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    while (DateTime.UtcNow < latest);
    return false;
  }
}
```

And then you would use it like this.

```
public static void Main()
{
  ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
  if (ConsoleEx.TryReadKey(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), out cki))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ReadKey returned a value.");
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ReadKey timed out.
  }
}
```